pdfbox3.0.1 generate a lot of warn message when start application to call pdfbox api
Warning Message
2024-09-18 10:14:02.363 WARN  -[]-[,,,,]-[http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.p.p.font.FileSystemFontProvider      651: 2478 new fonts found, font cache will be re-built
2024-09-18 10:14:02.365 WARN  -[]-[,,,,]-[http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.p.p.font.FileSystemFontProvider      366: Building on-disk font cache, this may take a while
2024-09-18 10:14:05.426 WARN  -[]-[,,,,]-[http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable   372: Unknown substFormat: 0
2024-09-18 10:14:05.427 WARN  -[]-[,,,,]-[http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable   372: Unknown substFormat: 256
2024-09-18 10:14:05.438 WARN  -[]-[,,,,]-[http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.p.p.font.FileSystemFontProvider      698: Could not load font file: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansPahawhHmong-Regular.ttf
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedShort(TTFDataStream.java:154)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readSingleLookupSubTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:345)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupSubtable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:259)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:313)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupList(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:247)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.read(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:102)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:365)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:66)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeFont(FileSystemFontProvider.java:692)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:392)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:271)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:170)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:72)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:892)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:530)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:505)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:282)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:330)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:247)
    at ...
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:898)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:809)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at com.nmt.ocr.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:765)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)  

fonts not found:

NotoSansPahawhHmong-Regular.ttf
NotoSansRejang-Regular.ttf
NotoColorEmoji.ttf
NotoSansOldPermic-Regular.ttf
NotoSansPauCinHau-Regular.ttf
NotoSansTagalog-Regular.ttf
NotoSansTaiViet-Regular.ttf
NotoSansGlagolitic-Regular.ttf
NotoSansOsage-Regular.ttf

It will occur in first time when start the application, i try to upgrade to 3.0.2 and 3.0.3 but still can't resolve
and the application running in docker container.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansPahawhHmong-Regular.ttf is broken. Delete it or replace it with the font from https://github.com/notofonts/pahawh-hmong/releases/tag/NotoSansPahawhHmong-v2.001

The current version (3.0.3) should no longer abort. And it should no longer check a font that is shown to be broken (see your .pdfbox.cache file, the font should have an entry that it is broken). Unless you're working in a container.

i will have a try, I am indeed running the application in a docker container

You should arrange your container so that PDFBox has already been run once, so that the appropriate .pdfbox.cache file exists in the user directory.

it is work, after upgrade pdfbox to 3.0.3, previously  i have upgraded pdfbox but without deploy latest docker image， Makes me think that upgrading dependencies doesn't work

You should still follow my advice re the .pdfbox.cache file, because the initial building of the font cache takes time. Unless the response time of your server isn't important.

Which function can trigger the building of font cache.

Try FontMappers.instance().getFontBoxFont("Arial", null);

And here's the check I used for a specific font file: new TTFParser(true).parse(new RandomAccessReadBufferedFile(new File("NotoSansPahawhHmong-Regular.ttf")));

I had tried FontMappers.instance().getFontBoxFont("Arial", null), it is work, thanks @TilmanHausherr

Summarizing my comments:
PDFBox builds a cache file with font information the first time a font is needed from disk, and this can take a long time. Older PDFBox versions sometimes aborted if a font was broken, or tried to access the font again and again, thus make sure you're using PDFBox 3.0.3 or 2.0.32.
If you're using PDFBox inside a container like docker, consider building the font information cache file (.pdfbox.cache in the user directory) before starting the container. This can be done with this command
FontMappers.instance().getFontBoxFont("Arial", null);

